# Is there a unique matrix $K \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ such that $KA + B$ is positive definite ($A$, $B$ given below)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Is there a unique matrix $K \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ (up to multiplication by a constant factor) such that 
$$K \begin{pmatrix}
0 &-1 
\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 
\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a positive definite matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $K = M\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ then $$K \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} = M + \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

There are many choices of $M$ that will work, like $\begin{bmatrix} c_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 + c_2\end{bmatrix}$ for any positive $c_1, c_2$. This corresponds to $K = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 + c_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ which are not scalar multiples of each other.